# Grid, size and position problem. html/css

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Here´s my project so far .

[image]

Im trying to make a grid that will be centered in the middle of the page. But im finding it impossible...

also the grid im making will only take the size of the pictures. like this:

[image]

Here is my code, uploaded it to replit but the pictures were store locally tho.

https://repl.it/@oNilian/ImpeccableBoringMp3

-> desired result. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj9nV.jpg

Comment: share your code.

Comment: You want only 4 columns per row?

Comment: Your requirement with code.

Comment: Your code should be here in the question itself, not just linked to from a third party site.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, i have changed your code css file.

```
.grid_columns {
    display: grid;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
   grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  }

.grid_columns div{
   padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;
}

.grid_columns div img{
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

in css file `grid-template-columns` change according to column number.
if 4 column grid. it should be like this,

```
grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
```

if it is 5 column. it should be like this.

```
grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
```

because sum of all the percentages should be 100%

img `width` should be changed to `%` value to make it responsive. I remove other values because of that.

```
.grid_columns div img{
  width: 100%;
 }
```

Here is my code in Repl.it

https://repl.it/repls/HonorableEffectiveCell

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, is it possible to make the grid in this way? https://i.imgur.com/RxvpHPJ.jpg

Comment: check this one.  ( https://repl.it/repls/HonorableEffectiveCell ) . i created separate 2 column grid for that